# I have been trying to identify the font shown in the picture without avail, and I would like some help

Tags: font-identification

While trying to find some Visual Studio Code-related settings, I stumbled upon an MS website which had the following snippet of code to show certain features of the VS Code. The font used in the snippet appears much more visually appealing than Courier New font that I currently use for my writing and development projects. I have tried all three well-known font identification websites (fontsquirrel, dafont, and fontfont), but I have not gotten a perfect match from them. I would greatly appreciate any help with the precise identification of the font.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in cases like this, you are better off typing "visual studio default typeface" into your favorite search engine rather than blindly using font identification.

This is most likely going to be Consolas or Cascadia Code (or Cascadia Mono).

See, for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/cascadia-code

Comment: If you were to make the line suggesting the font families the first line and make your suggestion on how to find fonts the second one, IMO, it would become the perfect answer. It actually is Consolas.